# gulp-tsc src folder not found

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp

I am trying to create and .net core application using Angular2.
I keep getting the following error

```
/wwwroot/NodeLib/gulp-tsc/src/compiler.ts' not found.
```

I cant figure out what i am missing.

***tsconfig.json***

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "outDir": "../wwwroot/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "angular2withvs2015",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.1.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.7",
    "gulp-tsc": "^1.2.5",
    "@types/node": "6.0.40"
  }
}
```

***Gulp.js***

```
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');

var gulp = require('gulp'),
 rimraf = require('rimraf');

gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
    return rimraf('./wwwroot/NodeLib/', cb)
});

gulp.task('copy:lib', function () {
    return gulp.src('node_modules/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/NodeLib/'));
});

gulp.task('copy:systemjs', function () {
    return gulp.src('Scripts/systemjs.config.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/'));
});
var tsProject = ts.createProject('Scripts/tsconfig.json', {
    typescript: require('typescript')
});
gulp.task('ts', function () {
    var tsResult = gulp.src("Scripts/**/*.ts") // instead of gulp.src(...)
        .pipe(tsProject());

    return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot'));
});


gulp.task('watch', ['watch.ts']);
gulp.task('watch.ts', ['ts'], function () {
    return gulp.watch('Scripts/**/*.ts', ['ts']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by \node_modules\gulp-tsc\tsconfig.json

```
"files": [
    "src/compiler.ts",
    "src/shellescape.ts",
    "src/tsc.ts"
  ]
```

When you execute gulp task **copy:lib**, content of node_modules is copied to **/wwwroot/NodeLib/**

According to my understanding entire content is not required. In my case I only wanted the content in **@angular**. So, I created a new gulp task,

```
gulp.task('copy:lib@angular', function () {
    return gulp.src('node_modules/@angular/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/NodeLib/@angular/'));
});
```

Then I deleted **NodeLib** folder in **wwwroot** and executed **copy:lib@angular** gulp task. It created new **NodeLib** folder which has only **@angular** folder in it. This solved Visual Studio compile error issue.

Comment: Thanks let me have a look

Answer (score 0):

gulp-tsc didn't seem to make well from 1.2.* to 1.3.* Not sure what the main contributor tries to do there, but 1.3.2 does not work yet for VS2015. IMHO you have 2 options:

1. work with gulp-tsc from git and copy referenced src directory to NodeLib/ or remove tsconfig.jason from there. I either case you will certainly have other dependencies broken for clean VS build.
2. you need to copy to NodeLib not only @angular as correctly suggested by Laksiri Fernando, but also every package referenced in your systemjs.config.js file as well as stuff you refer to at _Layout.cshtml environment tag.